# How to locate GIT commits about given diff in one given file?

Tags: git

Recently, a kernel panic occurs in UBIFS.

The solution provider suggests me to workaround by following patch:

```
/*
 * Re-erase the PEB before using it. This should minimize any issues
 * from decay of charge in this block.
 */
if (ubi->wl_is_inited) {
    err = ubi_wl_erase_peb(ubi, pnum);
    if (err)
        return err;
    }
```

However, I want to know which commit introduces this code slice and why.

Please kindly indicate the efficient git command to locate related commits.

Answer (score 1):

[`git blame`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame) is probably what you're looking for.

Simply use it like this:

```
git blame <filename>
```

Or you can specify what lines to look at:

```
git blame -L <start>,<end> <filename>
```